# Debug iOS extension with Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

Is there a way to debug an iOS extension (widget) with Xamarin? It never hits my breakpoints when I debug it on my physical device. Or at least a way to see logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging iOS extensions in Xamarin.iOS is not possible at this time and therefore breakpoints will not be hit.

The best way to debug an extension at the moment is to use `Console.WriteLine()` to print strings / variables to the console.

Edit: The current Alpha version of Xamarin Studio (6.2) does include the ability to debug extensions: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/#Debugging_iOS_App_Extension_Projects

Comment: When I debug my iPhone app on my physical device, I never see the `Console.WriteLine()` I write in the extension project. I'm looking in the Application Output window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Xamarin 6.2 supports debugging of iOS extensions: https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/studio/xamarin.studio_6.2/xamarin.studio_6.2/#Debugging_iOS_App_Extension_Projects